# What is the numpy equivalent of expand in pytorch?

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, array-broadcasting

Suppose I have a numpy array `x` of shape `[1,5]`. I want to expand it along axis 0 such that the resulting array `y` has shape [10,5] and `y[i:i+1,:]` is equal to `x` for each i.

If `x` were a pytorch tensor I could simply do

```
y = x.expand(10,-1)
```

But there is no `expand` in numpy and the ones that look like it (`expand_dims` and `repeat`) don't seem to behave like it.

---

Example:

```py
>>> import torch
>>> x = torch.randn(1,5)
>>> print(x)
tensor([[ 1.3306,  0.0627,  0.5585, -1.3128, -1.4724]])
>>> print(x.expand(10,-1))
tensor([[ 1.3306,  0.0627,  0.5585, -1.3128, -1.4724],
        [ 1.3306,  0.0627,  0.5585, -1.3128, -1.4724],
        [ 1.3306,  0.0627,  0.5585, -1.3128, -1.4724],
        [ 1.3306,  0.0627,  0.5585, -1.3128, -1.4724],
        [ 1.3306,  0.0627,  0.5585, -1.3128, -1.4724],
        [ 1.3306,  0.0627,  0.5585, -1.3128, -1.4724],
        [ 1.3306,  0.0627,  0.5585, -1.3128, -1.4724],
        [ 1.3306,  0.0627,  0.5585, -1.3128, -1.4724],
        [ 1.3306,  0.0627,  0.5585, -1.3128, -1.4724],
        [ 1.3306,  0.0627,  0.5585, -1.3128, -1.4724]])
```

Comment: numpy.reshape (https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) might be what you're looking for?

Comment: @DaveIdito No. reshape merely changes the shape, while `expand` essentially copies the data to new dimensions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can achieve that with [`np.broadcast_to`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_to.html#numpy.broadcast_to). But you can't use negative numbers:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.array([[ 1.3306,  0.0627,  0.5585, -1.3128, -1.4724]])
>>> print(np.broadcast_to(x,(10,5)))
[[ 1.3306  0.0627  0.5585 -1.3128 -1.4724]
 [ 1.3306  0.0627  0.5585 -1.3128 -1.4724]
 [ 1.3306  0.0627  0.5585 -1.3128 -1.4724]
 [ 1.3306  0.0627  0.5585 -1.3128 -1.4724]
 [ 1.3306  0.0627  0.5585 -1.3128 -1.4724]
 [ 1.3306  0.0627  0.5585 -1.3128 -1.4724]
 [ 1.3306  0.0627  0.5585 -1.3128 -1.4724]
 [ 1.3306  0.0627  0.5585 -1.3128 -1.4724]
 [ 1.3306  0.0627  0.5585 -1.3128 -1.4724]
 [ 1.3306  0.0627  0.5585 -1.3128 -1.4724]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `np.tile` which repeats the elements of a given axis as:

```py
>>> x = np.range(5)
>>> x = np.expand_dims(x, 0)
>>> x.shape
(1, 5)
>>> y = np.tile(x, (10, 1))  # repeat axis=0 10 times and axis=1 1 time
>>> y.shape
(10, 5)
```

Answer (score -1):

numpy has `numpy.newaxis`

```py
y = x[:, np.newaxis]
```

Comment: I think this is not what OP is lookingfor: This just adds a new dimension, but doesn't extend existing dimensions.

Comment: Expanding is usually used to multiply vector by matrix. numpy has broadcasting https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html so extending may be redundant

Comment: Yes indeed, that works exactly the same as in pytorch. But explicitly doing so uses a slightly different method.